# How to install pgAdmin 4 in server mode on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

How to install pgAdmin 4 on Ubuntu 16.04 ? Lack of information on homepage.

https://www.pgadmin.org/
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/

Comment: ... My question is about pgAdmin 4. There is pgAdmin 3 only in this repo.

Answer (score 19):

These are the steps I followed to make it run:

1) I didn't have `virtualenvwrapper` installed, so I (duh!) installed it

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

2) Standing on my home folder, I made a `pgadmin` virtual environment, which creates a `pgadmin` folder, inside of which I tell it to activate itself

```
cd ~
virtualenv pgadmin
cd pgadmin
source bin/activate
```

3) Inside my virtual environment, I make sure to have required dependencies so I'd be able to build `wheel` for `pycrypto` and `psycopg2`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libgmp3-dev
sudo pip install cryptography pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

4) Having the required deps, now I can download and pip install the latest pgadmin4 release

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.4/pip/pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl

pip install pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

5) pgAdmin4 is installed in my virtualenv, now I need to create a `config_local.py` in the same folder it was installed, and I will use `config.py`as the base. So, let's find that one first:

```
find . -wholename "*pgadmin4/config.py"
```

6) It tells me it's in `./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py` so now I can copy it and run pgAdmin4:

```
cp ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
python  ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

The webapp is now running at  http://localhost:5050

**### EDIT ###**

To avoid updating this thread each time a new version of pgAdmin4 is released, i made a [pgadmin4_installer repo at GitHub](https://github.com/InstaGIS/pgadmin4_installer) with:

- a detailed README.md
- an AptFile with system packages to install
- Makefile tasks to create virtualenvs specific to python2 or python3, according to your preference
- Makefile tasks to install requirements (python2 or python3)
- Instructions to run as an uwsgi script
- Instructions to create an uwsgi service with autostart on reboots

Comment: Dead link. 404.

Comment: how do I access it from other computer using ip. It accessible only by using localhost:5000

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute, there, I updated the package http link

Comment: what's the proper way of making this boot with the machine?

Comment: after creating an conf file in `/etc/init` you should be able to use `sudo update-rc.d uwsgi enable`. That, or create an entry in root's crontab like `@reboot  /usr/sbin/service uwsgi start &> /dev/null `

Answer (score 10):

Those are the instructions to install in **Server mode**. For **Desktop mode**, see [How to install pgAdmin 4 in desktop mode on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04).

For *pgAdmin 4 v1.4* on *Ubuntu 16.04*, according to the [download page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pip4.php):

#### Install dependencies, create a virtual environment, download, install & configure

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-pip libpq-dev

cd
virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate

wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.4/pip/pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl

pip install pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl

gedit lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

#### Configure `lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py`

```
# Minimum configuration for config_local.py
CSRF_SESSION_KEY = 'Change this now'
SECRET_KEY = 'Change this now'
SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT = 'Change this now'
```

#### Run

```
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

#### Access at http://localhost:5050

Comment: A note. If you need to start server later (e.g. schedule it to run at boot) final "Run" step won't work unless you execute "source bin/activate" every time prior to starting the server.

Comment: I am able not able to access using ip like : http://192.168.0.12:5050. It's only working on http://localhost:5050

Answer (score 4):

One way to install `pgadmin4` is to download its Python wheel at https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/v1.0-beta1/pip/ and then use `pip` to install it:

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/v1.0-beta1/pip/pgadmin4-1.0_beta1-py2-none-any.whl
pip install pgadmin4-1.0_beta1-py2-none-any.whl
```

Note that the wheel only works for Python 2. If you get an error message that says "Error: pg_config executable not found.", install `pg_config` by running `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` according to https://stackoverflow.com/q/11618898/486919.

According to https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pip4.php, to run `pgadmin4`, do the following:

> Once installed, you will need to create a `config_local.py` file in the
>   same directory as `config.py`. On a machine with a virtual environment
>   created at `~/pgadmin4`, this is
>   `~/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4`. Ensure you set values
>   for the `SECRET_KEY`, `SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT` and `CSRF_SESSION_KEY`
>   settings at bare minimum - see `config.py` for more information and
>   other settings that can be customised. In order to reference other
>   variables from `config.py`, you may need to include `from config import *`
>   at the top of `config_local.py`.
>
> pgAdmin can now be run with a command like `python
>   ~/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py`. Finally,
>   point your browser to http://127.0.0.1:5050.

Comment: While the pip install finished successfully, I'm not sure where to do from here. The binary for pgadmin4 does not get built/installed. Can someone provide further instructions?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of the question and this answer. Consider asking a new question if no duplicates exist.

Comment: Why is it beyond the scope? The question is "how to install pgadmin4" and the answer does not actually install it.

Comment: @JonathanDunlap If the pip installation is successful, then pgAdmin 4 is indeed installed and you can run pgAdmin 4. Read https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pip4.php to see how to do it. I just tried it out and it works for me. Therefore, what you are really asking is "how to run pgAdmin 4", which is a different question from OP's question asking "how to install it".  I could have also added instructions on how to run it, but that would just be me going beyond what OP asked for and therefore strictly optional as far as I am concerned.

Comment: My god that is pedantic.  The last step of installing it is running it.  I came here, and I have the same question.  Is the purpose of this site to help people or to be pedantic?

Comment: Just came here with the same question and saw this answer. I've created and account here just to downvote this guy, jesus.

Comment: Woah, calm down people. Surely we can agree to disagree on how to interpret what "install" means. Installing and running are still distinct in my opinion, but since you both wanted to also know how to run `pgadmin4`, I will include instructions on how to do so.