# unable to deploy pgadmin4 on Ubuntu in server mode

Tags: server, python, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I followed [How to install pgAdmin 4 in server mode on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788457/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-server-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04) to configure pgadmin4 on my Ubuntu server successfully.

It says navigate to http://localhost:5050 in your browser.

But, my Ubuntu machine is a server that has IP address ***.***.**.*** and I don't know how I can test my pgadmin using that IP as localhost.

I used these commands to create pgAdmin4:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
cd ~
virtualenv pgadmin
cd pgadmin
source bin/activate
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libgmp3-dev
sudo pip install cryptography pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libgmp3-dev
sudo pip install cryptography pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 
find . -wholename "*pgadmin4/config.py"
cp ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
python  ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Comment: Have you tried http://[your.server.ip.address]:5050 ?

Comment: thanks for response ..i tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin4 has a config file namely config.py possibly located in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4. In which, change the DEFAULT_SERVER = '' instead of 'localhost', so pgAdmin4 can be access from a public IP address.