# Pgadmin4 wheel installation does not install pgadmin4.py

Tags: software-installation, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am following these instructions to install pgadmin4 in my local machine:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libgmp3-dev virtualenv python-pip libpq-dev python-dev

cd /opt/
mkdir enviromentpy
cd enviromentpy/
sudo virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate

sudo wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.6/pip/pgadmin4-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl

sudo pip install pgadmin4-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

These steps run fine, however I cannot find the pgadmin4.py file to run the following command:

```
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

What I am doing it wrong?

These commands I took from this website (Changing only the version of pgadmin4 - but either way it does not work): http://yallalabs.com/linux/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I also followed the instructions from this asnwer: [How to install pgAdmin 4 in server mode on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788457/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-server-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04) But no luck.

Comment: please use cd lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/ sudo python pgAdmin4.py

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* Had the exact same problem, managed to solve it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-pip libpq-dev python-dev
cd
virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate



bin/pip install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/pip/pgadmin4-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```